# Textfile to Avrofile in hadoop using Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I need to convert the textfile to avrofile in  hadoop hdfs using mapreduce.

I already placed text file in hdfs.

I didnt know how to implement in mapreduce.

Comment: I would suggest starting here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html .  Also check out the [tour[, and [ask] plus [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This and example demonstrating how to convert text file to Avro
 (Our input file is a movie database, contains the following information )

serial number :: movie name (year)::tag1|tag2

Example Records :

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
8::Tom and Huck (1995)::Adventure|Children's
```

Result Schema is :

```
{
"name":"movies",
"type":"record",
"fields":[
 {"name":"movieName",
 "type":"string"
 },

{"name":"year",
 "type":"string"
 },

{"name":"tags",
 "type":{"type":"array","items":"string"}
 }
 ]

}
```

**CODE EXAMPLE :**
The map function will extract the different fields from the input record and constructs a generic record. The reduce function will simply write it’s key to the output, no processing is done in reducer.

```
 public class MRTextToAvro extends Configured implements Tool{ 
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int exitCode=ToolRunner.run(new MRTextToAvro(),args );
         System.out.println("Exit code "+exitCode); 
     }

     public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
         Job job= Job.getInstance(getConf(),"Text To Avro");

         job.setJarByClass(getClass());

         FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(arg0[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(arg0[1]));
         Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
         Schema schema=parser.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("movies.avsc"));
         job.getConfiguration().setBoolean(
         Job.MAPREDUCE_JOB_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST, true);
         AvroJob.setMapOutputKeySchema(job,schema);
         job.setMapOutputValueClass( NullWritable.class);
         AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, schema);

         job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
         job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyOutputFormat.class);

         job.setMapperClass(TextToAvroMapper.class);
         job.setReducerClass(TextToAvroReduce.class);

         return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
     }

     public static class TextToAvroMapper extends Mapper&lt;LongWritable ,Text,AvroKey&lt;GenericRecord&gt;,NullWritable&gt;{
         Schema schema;

         protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         super.setup(context);
         Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
         schema=parser.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("movies.avsc"));
     }

     public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
         GenericRecord record=new GenericData.Record(schema);
         String inputRecord=value.toString();

         record.put("movieName", getMovieName(inputRecord));
         record.put("year", getMovieRelaseYear(inputRecord));
         record.put("tags", getMovieTags(inputRecord));
         context.write(new AvroKey(record), NullWritable.get());
         } 
         public String getMovieName(String record){
         String movieName=record.split("::")[1];
         return movieName.substring(0, movieName.lastIndexOf('(' )).trim();
         }
         public String getMovieRelaseYear(String record){
         String movieName=record.split("::")[1];
         return movieName.substring( movieName.lastIndexOf( '(' )+1,movieName.lastIndexOf( ')' )).trim();
         }
         public String[] getMovieTags(String record){
         return (record.split("::")[2]).split("\\|");
         }
     }

     public static class TextToAvroReduce extends Reducer&lt;AvroKey&lt;GenericRecord&gt;,NullWritable,AvroKey&lt;GenericRecord&gt;,NullWritable&gt;{
     @Override
         public void reduce(AvroKey&lt;GenericRecord&gt; key,Iterable&lt;NullWritable&gt; value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
         context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
     }
     }
    }
```

To run the job , you need to put the avro related lib on class path

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/targets/avro-mapred-1.7.4-hadoop2.jar

yarn jar HadoopAvro-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar MRTextToAvro -libjars avro-mapred-1.7.4-hadoop2.jar /input/path output/path
```

[image: Resulting Avro file]

Comment: Thanks Saghe Achraf ,movies.avsc is a schema file where should i place this file? in input folder?

Comment: You're welcome , yes you place it in input folder specified by **args[0]**